# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, testcontainers

I've created a Scala project that creates a testcontainer (via com.dimafeng.testcontainers) with two Docker's containers (singularities/datastore-emulator and bigtruedata/gcloud-pubsub-emulator). The testcontainer is successfully created, when I run the docker ps command this is what I see:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
ddc16471205a        quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.2   "/app"              2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32771->8080/tcp   testcontainers-ryuk-371a41c2-3d23-426f-943d-608a816c96d3
```

Now, the problem occurs when I try to run the container:

```
$ docker run -p 4000:80 quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.2
2018/12/13 10:59:48 Starting on port 8080...
panic: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/bsideup/moby-ryuk/main.go:31 +0xe2e
```

And if I go inside the container and run the /app command this is what I get:

```
$ docker exec -it ddc /bin/sh
/ # /app
2018/12/13 11:40:55 Starting on port 8080...
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x64f8d6]

goroutine 9 [running]:
main.main.func1(0xc4200685a0, 0xc4201bd890, 0xc420068600)
    /go/src/github.com/bsideup/moby-ryuk/main.go:42 +0x286
created by main.main
    /go/src/github.com/bsideup/moby-ryuk/main.go:39 +0x1b5
```

I've tried literally everything from setting the docker-machine eval default to check all the possible permissions problems. What am I missing?

(I have no access at all to the go files present in the errors)

Here's the information about my docker installation

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:47:43 2018
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.0
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       4d60db4
  Built:            Wed Nov  7 00:55:00 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

And the infos

```
$ docker info
Containers: 19
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 18
Images: 7
Server Version: 18.09.0
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.125-linuxkit
Operating System: Docker for Mac
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 1.952GiB
Name: linuxkit-025000000001
ID: 5XHJ:QGZD:4I55:WLU6:RLUF:E5XL:XFUL:PMBB:D432:IJFX:EUPG:QEVW
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 33
 Goroutines: 58
 System Time: 2018-12-13T11:34:52.2335167Z
 EventsListeners: 2
HTTP Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3128
HTTPS Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3129
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Comment: What I see at the documentation page [here](https://github.com/testcontainers/moby-ryuk) is that you have to also use `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` in your `docker run ...` command.

Comment: Oh my god... thank you, I didn't see that option

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this (or add to .zshrc)

```
export TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE=$(colima ls -j | jq -r '.address')
export TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE=/var/run/docker.sock
export DOCKER_HOST=unix://$HOME/.colima/default/docker.sock
```

Worked for me!